# How to disable a button for input validation in FXML

Tags: java, validation, button, javafx, fxml

I have two fields: username and password. I want a button to remain disabled if these fields are blank or their length is less and n characters.

I tried using button `disableProperty()` in my controller but I want to do the validation in the FXML file. I don't know if it's possible or not.

My current validation:

```
    @FXML
    private TextField usernameField;
    @FXML
    private PasswordField passwordField;
    @FXML
    private Button signinButton;

    // Runs on initializing
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        signinButton.disableProperty().bind(usernameField.textProperty().isEmpty()
                .or(usernameField.textProperty().length().lessThan(5))
                .or(passwordField.textProperty().isEmpty())
                .or(passwordField.textProperty().length().lessThan(4)));
    }
```

FXML file:

```
<TextField fx:id="usernameField" prefHeight="34.0" prefWidth="220.0" promptText="Username"/>
<PasswordField fx:id="passwordField" prefHeight="34.0" prefWidth="220.0" promptText="Password"/>
<Button fx:id="signinButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onSignin" prefWidth="220.0" text="Sign in"/>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why? That's what controllers are made for.

Comment: I though it's better to separate the view validations and logic code.

Comment: Then don't put logic code in your FXML controller.

Comment: This is “view logic”, which belongs in the controller. The [Eden coding tutorial in MVC](https://edencoding.com/mvc-in-javafx/) nicely distinguishes between “view logic” (controller) and “business logic” (model).

Comment: @James_D unfortunately the eden coding tutorial in MVC is broken. Most of the content is missing.  The part obout view vs business is still there without the examples anymore.  Luckily the content can still be found in the [wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20220818080516/https://edencoding.com/mvc-in-javafx/).